# How to Update ObservableCollection with a new thread and access its items from another UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, observablecollection

I'm working on a project about PDF rendering in the C# language. I convert each page of PDF file to Image and Adds it to a `ObservableCollection` with a new thread by the below code:

```
  ThreadStart myThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(DoWork);
  myThread = new Thread(myThreadDelegate);
  myThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

  void DoWork()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pdfFile.Pages.Count; i++)
        {
            PdfPage page=pdfFile.LoadPage(i);
            myObservableCollection[i]=page;
        }
    }
```

then pass the custom item of myObservableCollection to another UserControl for render it but I got an exception:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

I know if I use UI thread my problem could be solved but I want load pdf pages in the background and user doesn't wait for loading all pages and this is possible with a new thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use threads but have to use the `Dispatcher` to access UI elements. Only the part, where you pass the item to the `UserControl` has to be done by the dispatcher.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => AddItem()));
```

`BeginInvoke` is a asynchronous call and won't block the execution of the following code.

**Edit:** I'm still not 100% sure if I unterstood the whole idea of your application but made a small sample which demonstrates how you can use threads and UI elements.

I made a `Window` (that would be your `UserControl`) which contains a `Button` and a `ListBox`. When clicking the `Button` a thread is started and processes some items. In my case it just adds some texts into a list, I added `Thread.Sleep(1000)` to simulate the processing of lots of stuff. When the text is prepared, it will be added to the `ObservableCollection`, which has to be done by the UI thread (`Dispatcher`). There is nothing blocking the UI but this adding and this is done very fast. You can also start multiple threads at the same time.

This is the code-behind of the `Window` (the `Window` itsself just contains a `Button` and a `ListBox`):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> textList;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        textList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        InitializeComponent();
        btnStartWork.Click += BtnStartWorkClick;
        lstTextList.ItemsSource = textList;
    }

    private void BtnStartWorkClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread myThread;
        ThreadStart myThreadDelegate = DoWork;
        myThread = new Thread(myThreadDelegate);
        myThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        myThread.Start();
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            string text = string.Format("Text {0}", i);
            // block the thread (but not the UI)
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            // use the dispatcher to add the item to the list, which will block the UI, but just for a very short time
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textList.Add(text)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chris Shain - Could you please explain this?

Comment: but It didn't solve my problem, it takes too time for loading all contents.

Comment: Not sure if I got your problem. Of course the loading of the pdfs will take time, but your UI thread would just block for rendering the image which you created. The loading of the pdf wouldn't block the UI.

Comment: @MatthiasG sorry misread the answer- this should work, but I'd add that you may need to *create* the observableCollection on the UI thread first

Comment: Could you add some more code, especially how you use the ObservableCollection in combination with your UserControl? I could than adjust my code sample.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I created my ObservableCollection and a new thread in my UserControl constructor and start a new thread for update ObservableCollection when a button Clicked. also I had another button that when raised, show custom item of ObservableCollection. but when I add the Dispatcher to a new thread and then start it, it locks UI. Could you give me full sample code to do something like this?

Comment: @Siyamak Shahpasand - I added a code sample, not sure if this is what you want to do.